# How do I remove an extra space while performing the split function?

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup, space

I need to use the vlookup function and the space in front of the first name is being an issue

I tried the data clean up to trim white spaces but it didn't work.
I used the split function to split the name value (last name, first name) into separate values. After that I used the concantenate function to merge it into first name (space) last name, however, the space in front of the split value remains!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `TRIM` function to remove any extra spaces from these values before concatenating them again. Example: `=TRIM(A2) & " " & TRIM(B2)`.

You should also remove any leading or trailing spaces from your lookup value by incorporating the `TRIM` function into your `VLOOKUP`: `=VLOOKUP(TRIM(X2), A2:B100, 2, FALSE)`.

**Note**: If you want to trim an entire column, you can use: `=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(A:A))` in a blank cell outside the range.

Answer (score 0):

If your names are in the form `Last, First` and you want them in the form `First Last`, you can use:

```
=JOIN(" ",CHOOSECOLS(SPLIT(A1,", ",FALSE),2,1))
```

You could also use `REGEXREPLACE`:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"(.*), (.*)","$2 $1")
```